# Speaker hum, power supply or motherboard?

Tags: audio, motherboard, power-supply, speakers

I recently purchased a new set of speakers only to find they hum when connected to my PC.

I have tried these speakers on multiple other devices and there is never a hum.

On stripping down my PC to only the motherboard and power supply I have found that as soon as the power supply is plugged in the speakers start to hum.

This happens even when the power supply is turned off either at the mains or on the supply. The only way to stop the hum is to unplug the power supply from the mains.

I have a few questions:

1) Is the hum more likely to be caused by the power supply or motherboard?
(I'm assuming that the power supply is causing some kind of loop, though it seems strange it would do it when switched off)

2) If I don't fix this issue now, any new audio device could suffer the same problem?

3) Is there a way to fix this without buying a new power supply/motherboard/speakers? (I have no problem with upgrading either of the parts, just would like to know my options)

Comment: Based on the information you shared there really is no way for us to say either way.  Both the power supply and the motherboard have components that could cause RF noise.

Comment: @Ramhound is there any further testing I can do to try and find out which it is?

Comment: This is a ground loop. the first thing to do is ensure you are plugging your speakers into the same outlet as the PSU.

Comment: @Yorik, yes they are plugged into the same outlet

Comment: One trick for diagnosing this is to make a second ground connection from the two devices: attach a piece of speaker wire to a ground point of the speakers, and then touch the other end to the case, the psu external housing. (with the psu turned off). You might find that the hum lessens a little. then decide what to do.

Comment: Are you hearing *hum* (low frequency) or *hiss* (high frequency)?  Hum is power or ground related, whereas hiss many causes.  Describe the speakers; are they self-powered or passive like ordinary hifi speakers? *"as soon as the power supply is plugged in the speakers start to hum"* -- The PSU does provide the electricity that the PC system needs to operate, so this really isn't out of the ordinary (unless you have self-powered speakers).  Have you tried attaching a *different* pair of speakers?.

Comment: I am hearing a hum, the subwoofer is mains powered and the speakers are then powered by the subwoofer. If the speakers are not connected to the PC but connected to the same mains there is no hum so I'm assuming the power interference is coming from the PC. Oddly my cheaper set of speakers/subwoofer don't hum when connected to the PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a fairly common phenomenon with laptops (but it happens with phones often enough). If your audio device works digitally, you'll likely never notice an issue, some USB devices with bad design may generate hum.

Any device you plug in could "suffer" the same problem.

You don't need a new mobo, just have the audio processed and output in a different way. If you're looking at analog solutions, find a low-pass filter that can cut out 60hz to 50hz range before you hit your speakers of course.

If you're the spendy type grab a DAC and use that as your audio interface instead of a direct connection to your computer. They're often designed specifically to avoid line-in or line-out hum.

Comment: would that be the same this as a ground loop isolator?

Comment: That's more on the nose, that might actually work.

Comment: If you were talking about a DAC (a digital to analog converter), it's an external audio device usually used by audio professionals. It's effectively an external sound card sometimes w/ their own power supply.

Comment: Following your comments about filters, I ended up searching for a speaker hum filter, which in turn led me to a ground loop isolator. Hopefully that does that trick!

Comment: I was wondering about the sudden hop to ground loop isolator, because a ground loop is the classic culprit for noise in a lot of electronics. If it doesn't fix the issue, I'd take a shot at a DAC.

Answer (score 1):

Hum doesn't come only from ground loops. A bad filter input electrolytic capacitor in the power supply, the one that comes after the rectifier, can introduce lots of hum that could affect the internal audio chip. So this hum can be mounted over the audio signal. Not 100% guaranteed, but replacing the PSU, the capacitor or the motherboard itself could be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

From Google (Ground Loop): "NORTH AMERICAN
an unwanted electric current path in a circuit resulting in stray signals or interference, occurring, e.g., when two earthed points in the same circuit have different potentials."

So, plug them into DIFFERENT Circuits and it should be solved.

Comment: Unfortunately I have already tried plugging the speakers into a different ground and that does not solve the problem

Comment: Are you certain that the different outlets are actually on different circuits?

Comment: You are interpreting this wrong: the "circuit" is the computer and the speaker system interconnected by the audio cable. The "two earthed points" are the ground connections at the two different wall outlets.

Comment: I suppose it is possible they are not, but I only have 6 sockets to chose from and I've chosen the two least likely to be connected.

Comment: in that case plugging them into different circuits wouldn't really solve anything as I'm trying to get audio from the computer